# Measurability of a shift operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $C$ denote the space of continuous functions $f : [ 0, \infty ) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ equipped with the metric
$$
d(f,g) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left( 1 \wedge \sup_{x \in [0, n]} |f(x) - g(x)| \right)2^{-n},
$$
and let $\mathscr{B}(C)$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $C$. I am trying to show that, for every $y \geq 0$, the shift operator
$$
\theta_y : C \rightarrow C, \quad f(x) \mapsto f ( x + y), \ x \in [ 0, \infty). 
$$
is $\mathscr{B}(C)-\mathscr{B}(C)$-measurable.

For example, I thought about showing that $\theta_y$ is continuous (or even uniformly continuous). For this, let $\varepsilon> 0$ and $f_0 \in C$ be fixed. Then, if $d(f, f_0) < \varepsilon$, is it posible to show that
$$
d(\theta_y f, \theta_y f_0) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left( 1 \wedge \sup_{x \in [0, n]} |f(x+y) - f_0(x+y)| \right)2^{-n} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left( 1 \wedge \sup_{x \in [y, n+y]} |f(x) - f_0(x)| \right)2^{-n}
$$
is less than some multiple of $\varepsilon$? Is there possibly a more straightforward approach that does not resort to showing the continuity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach you started, via showing continuity works well:

The $n$th summand in the series
$$
d(\theta_y f, \theta_y f_0) =    \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left( 1 \wedge \sup_{x \in [y, n+y]} |f(x) - f_0(x)| \right)2^{-n}
$$
is bounded above by $2^{\lceil y \rceil}$ times the summand with index $m=n+\lceil y \rceil$  in the series
$$
d(f,g) = \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \left( 1 \wedge \sup_{x \in [0, m]} |f(x) - g(x)| \right)2^{-m} \,.
$$